# Unable to create core on solr 4.3.1

Tags: solr

I'm trying to create a new core on Solr(version 4.3.1). However, it gives me the following error in Tomcat's catlina.out

```
    1182302654 [http-8191-25] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'PWR-11
    223344': Could not get shard_id for core: PWR-11223344 coreNodeName:172.1.2.3:8191_icxn2_PWR-11223344
            at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:525)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:144)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:608)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:206)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not get shard_id for core: PWR-11223344 coreNodeName:172.1.2.3:8191_icxn2_PWR-11223344

at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.doGetShardIdProcess(ZkController.java:1224)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1303)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.registerCore(CoreContainer.java:776)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.register(CoreContainer.java:869)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:521)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: It requires more details about installation of Solr Cloud. By the way, this version is very old. Use latest stable version that is 9.2 now